# How to use the spread players in the air on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to use the `/spreadplayers` command to make a rain of arrows. Therefore, I need them to spread in the air, 10 blocks or so above the ground or player.

```
/execute @a[score_Arrows_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon Arrow ~ ~10 ~
/execute @a[score_Arrows_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /spreadplayers ~ ~ 0 5 false @e[type=Arrow]
```

These commands make the arrows teleport to the ground, instead of placing them in the air.

How do I use the `/spreadplayers` command to spread entities in the air?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spreadplayers will always teleport entities to solid ground (no water, air, or lava).

You can instead spread them, then immediately teleport them upwards:

```
/execute @a[score_Arrows_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon Arrow ~ ~3 ~
/execute @a[score_Arrows_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /spreadplayers ~ ~ 0 5 false @e[type=Arrow]
/execute @a[score_Arrows_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /tp @e[type=Arrow] ~ ~10 ~
```